# Photoshop saving action selecting layers by name

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I would like to know if it's possible to make a photshop action which does the following in a single psd file:

- make one layer visible (was invisible before) with a specific name, for example "one"
- make another layer invisible (was visible before) with a specific name, for example "two"
- saving this document naming it "name_01.jpg" being 01 a sequence number
- make the layer "two" invisible
- make the layer "three" visible (was visible before)
- saving this document as "name_02"
- and so on, for about twenty layers

Is there any way to code this? I've been searching around for some time now and I can't find anything even remotely related.

Many thanks!

Comment: To answer your question: yes, it is possible. And yes, there’s a way to code this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may help in improving your question

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to find the code you need for your specific needs just lying around on the internet.

Life's not that easy.

There are however, plenty of places to pick up the basic concepts. Here's the bare bones of what you need. I suggest you modify it with a loop:

```
// call the source document
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument

// get layer "one"
app.activeDocument.activeLayer = app.activeDocument.artLayers.getByName("one");
// set it's visibility to be true
app.activeDocument.activeLayer.visible = true;

// get layer "two"
app.activeDocument.activeLayer = app.activeDocument.artLayers.getByName("two");
// set it to ve invisible
app.activeDocument.activeLayer.visible = false;

// set the name of the file here [CHANGE THIS]
var filePath = "c:\mypath\name_01.jpg";

// save as jpeg
save_as_jpeg(filePath);


app.activeDocument.activeLayer = app.activeDocument.artLayers.getByName("one");
app.activeDocument.activeLayer.visible = false;

app.activeDocument.activeLayer = app.activeDocument.artLayers.getByName("two");
app.activeDocument.activeLayer.visible = true;

// set the name of the file here [CHANGE THIS]
filePath = "c:\mypath\name_02.jpg";

// save as jpeg
save_as_jpeg(filePath);



function save_as_jpeg(filePath)
{
  // Flatten the jpg
  activeDocument.flatten();

  // jpg file options
  var jpgFile = new File(filePath);
  jpgSaveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
  jpgSaveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.OPTIMIZEDBASELINE;
  jpgSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
  jpgSaveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;
  jpgSaveOptions.quality = myJpgQuality;

  activeDocument.saveAs(jpgFile, jpgSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);

  //close without saving
  app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
}
```

What you're looking for is a way to take the above code and [loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) over it so it does layers one through to twenty.